typescript - get return type of current anonymous function
Is there a way in typescript to easily get the return type of the function you're currently in?
Eg
const fn = (): (some complex type that I don't want to repeat or name)[] => {
    const result: ReturnTypeOfThisFunction = [];
    // generate result
    return result;
};

I want to have the function itself have an explicit type, not derive it from the return value, but also not repeat the type within the function body, or declare a type just for this one-off function.
If the function was a named top level function I could just do ReturnType<typeof functionName> but if it's an anonymous function, or one within a class, object, etc, then this gets increasingly complicated

Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] without pseudocode and where we can play around with it in our IDEs.

It's not that easy with generics and/or conditional types https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=5.6.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKjApgDylsAEwhmgCcBLMAcwB8wBXAWwCMsyA+ACgEMzqAXDHQBtALoBKIZlz4iJclWowA-DADkimuvEwh6xq3Y6xyDjADeAKBgxQkWCAZQhAJSxQGZMOgCeAByxUKACsEDh4MHMUcQBuGxgyDy9EJyh4gF8gA

For your example, this is pretty easy with the TypeScript utility type ReturnType.
type SomeComplexType = {
    a: number
}

const fn = (): SomeComplexType[] => {
    const result: ReturnType<typeof fn> = [];
    // generate result
    return result;
};

Playground
Note that this is not a way to get the return type of the "function you are currently in," which I suspect is impossible with arrow functions, and probably should be (you can't call them recursively either).
But because you're assigning it to a named constant, you can access it via that constant.
